# Best practice using null in a ternary operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hey first time poster/user, I have been working through some coding exercises. I wrote a piece of code that passed tests but I am unsure if this is best practice

In this sample I am iterating over an array using the filter function.  I am using a call back function that will return words with length greater than 5.

sample code

```
const words = ['unique', 'uncanny', 'pique', 'oxymoron', 'guise'];

const interestingWords = words.filter(word => {
    return word ? word.length > 5 : null
})
```

In my head if the condition isn't met it shouldn't even try to return. What is happening when I return a null?  or is this a case where I wouldn't use ternary at all.

The best I got was from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

> The value null is written with a literal: null. null is not an identifier for a property of the global object, like undefined can be. Instead, null expresses a lack of identification, indicating that a variable points to no object. In APIs, null is often retrieved in a place where an object can be expected but no object is relevant.

So should I refrain from returning a null in this context?

Comment: `words.filter(word=>word.length>5);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `.filter`'s callback cares about is the truthy or falsey value returned inside it. Here, it'd be better to return that comparison directly, no conditional operator needed:

```
const interestingWords = words.filter(word => word.length > 5);
```

A construction like

```
return word ? word.length > 5 : null
```

could make sense if you needed to check a *sub-property*, but only if the array element existed first, eg:

```js
const objects = [
  null,
  { word: 'foo' },
  { word: 'barbar' },
  null
];

const interestingObjects = objects.filter(
  obj => obj ? obj.word.length > 5 : null
);
console.log(interestingObjects);
```

Answer (score 1):

If elements of the array might be `null` or `undefined`, you can use the optional chaining operator.

```
const interestingWords = words.filter(word => {
    return word?.length > 5
})
```

Comment: You know I have seen chaining in SWIFT before. Its something I need to get more familiar with thanks for your feedback